# PicKit3 and PIC16F1829 programming, MCLR voltage

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

I just started with microchip world.

I'm about to buy a PicKit3 and i've seen it can outputs from 1.8V to 14V MCLR.

The pic i will use is the PIC16F1829 and it should work with MCLR @ 5V.

In the datasheet it seems i would need a zener/shunt to limit the voltage.
First of all isn't there a board ready to play with?

Can i use LVP? If so using MPLab 8 IDE how do i change in LVP?
Is the pin connection the same?

Since i haven't bought it yet i would rather avoid burning a pic

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IDE i've set the voltage appropriately and everything went ok on its own.
I didn't have to enable anything fancy

Answer (score 0):

Notes at the bottom of page 345 in the PIC16F1829 data sheet (DS40001440E) recommends using a voltage limit circuit when using the ICD2 device programmer.

According to Microchip this is "not required" when using the PICkit3.

Get a few extra PIC16F1829 just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You ask about boards ready to use, take a look at the Curisotiy Nano boards 
https://www.microforum.cc/topic/9-microchip-xpress-evaluation-boards

These are ready to use and do not need any programmer. You can simply send a file to these devices over USB. They are also have debugging capability.

In terms of the 14V on MCLR, the device is designed to handle whatever pulse will be generated by the PICkit3, so you do not need any protection for the PIC against that. In fact limiting the voltage on that pin will prevent the device from programming so you definitely do not want to do that. If you are however using this pin to connect to other parts on your board the other parts probably will need protection.

You can most definitely use LVP, just be careful, it is possible to use LVP to disable LVP, and then the only way to get it back on is to use HVP!

Lastly in the IDE under programming options you can change the mode there (Use low voltage programming mode entry)

[image]